# Crear una tabla en mysql con algunos campos inmodificables

Tags: python, mysql

Estoy usando mysql. Mi idea es que una vez que se inserte un registro en una tabla, se puedan modificar solo algunos campos de ese registro.

Lo resolvi desde python,mostrandole al usuario las opciones modificables,
pero mi duda es si esto se puede resolver desde mysql al momento de crear la tabla por ejemplo.

Comment: Una opción es gestionarlo mediante usuarios con permisos únicamente para hacer `SELECT`. Intenta algo en esa línea y te respondo con el código completo

Comment: Si lo resolvieras desde MySQL ¿Cómo sabría el usuario cuáles campos no puede modificar?

Comment: Que queres que se haga al crear la tabla? utilizar distintos usuarios con permisos distintos para generar reglas de negocios (que se llaman asi) es una mala idea... que pasa si tenes usuarios con permisos distintos en tu sistema??? vas a tener distintos usuarios de base de datos???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Existe 2 niveles en MySQL.

##### El prime nivel se trata sobre permisos de usuarios.

##### Segundo nivel se trata de db.

En ese segundo nivel puedes decidir que tabla se puede modificar de una base de datos e incluso que columnas de dichas tablas. Se puede ver esto permiso con :

```
SELECT USER,HOST.SELECT_PRIV,UPDATE_PRIV FROM MYSQL.USER;
```

Te mostrara el usuario con donde se conecta y si puede hacer ***UPDATE y SELECT*** sobre esa tabla.

***Por ejemplo :*** Quieres dar permisos de ***SELECT*** sobre los campo de una tabla pues seria algo similar a esto :

```
GRANT SELECT(COLUMNA1,COLUMNA3) ON TuBaseDato.TuTabla TO 'TuUSuario'@'TuHost';
```

Imagínate que tienes la ***base de datos empresa*** con ***la tabla empleados*** cuyas ***columnas son : dni,nombre,ap1,ap2,sueldo,fechaNac.***

Y solo queremos que el ***usuario pepito*** ***conectado desde localhost*** solo pueda ***ver el nombre y el ap1,*** por motivos de seguridad, pues se haría de la siguiente forma.

```
GRANT SELECT(nombre,ap1) ON empresa.empleados TO 'pepito'@'localhost';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]